# permutations of a list java

Tags: java, permutation, generic-programming

I am trying to generate all possible permutations of a given list in a generic function. I think I have the function code correct. However, during testing time I keep getting compiler errors from my main program. Please help!

```
import java.util.*;

class perms <E>{

  public List<List<E>> generatePerm(List<E> original) {
      if (original.size() == 0) { 
          List<List<E>> result = new ArrayList<List<E>>();
          result.add(new ArrayList<E>());
          return result;
      }

      E firstElement = original.remove(0);
      List<List<E>> returnValue = new ArrayList<List<E>>();
      List<List<E>> permutations = generatePerm(original);

      for (List<E> smallerPermutated : permutations) {
          for (int index=0; index <= smallerPermutated.size(); index++) {
              List<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>(smallerPermutated);
              temp.add(index, firstElement);
              returnValue.add(temp);
          }
      }

      return returnValue;
  }

  public static void main(String[] params){
      List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
      p.add(1);
      p.add(2);

      System.out.print(p.toString());

      List<List<Integer>> resultantList=generatePerm(p);

      System.out.print(resultantList.toString());
  }
}
```

I keep generating the following error in my testing portion:

```
perms.java:33: generatePerm(java.util.List<E>) in perms<E> cannot be applied to (java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>)
List<List<Integer>> resultantList=generatePerm(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not helpful at all; the real problem is that you are calling a method that belongs to an object, but don't provide an object. If it wasn't for generics you would get the famous "cannot call non-static method from static context" error.

One way to fix it is creating an object:

```
  perms<Integer> computation = new perms<Integer>();
  List<List<Integer>> resultantList = computation.generatePerm(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `generatePerm` function is not `static`: as `main` is `static` you won't call a `non-static` function from a `static` context.
2. You should put an `<E>` after the access modifier of `generatePerm` declaration to specify that this function is generic.

So working version of `generatePerm` function would be:

```
public static <E>List<List<E>> generatePerm(List<E> original) { 
  //your code block

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot 2 things:

- make `generatePerm()` `static`
- then you have to make `generatePerm()` generic adding `<E>`
- (java convention) class names begin with capital letter - rename class to `Perms`

Result:

```
public class Perms
...
public static <E> List<List<E>> generatePerm(List<E> original)
...
```

Btw you don't have to declare `<E>` in class definition because here you use it only in static context.